# Allow user to resize child windows in OOBA

Tags: c#, silverlight, resize

Is where a standart way to allow user to resize a childwindow (not just the main) in Silverlight OOB app? 
The only solution i have now is to create a clickable area and handle mouse events there but at that point i have troubles with layout slots (between borders of real window and it's content there is some space). So to create a standart "Resize Edge" i have to play with negative margin values... 
If there is no standart way maybe there is more pretty decision then the above one?

Comment: Click "Add comment" in this page.  Note the grip in the lower right corner of the box.  That's pretty standard.

Comment: @HansPassant, the question is how to implement the same thing in Silverlight, without handling events.

Comment: I wanted the same thing... but standart template for child windows doesn't allow to add some interactive object right in the bottom right corner (or any other corner) - the margin between content we make and border of window is "7" - and without changing template i can't reduce it.